# Error loading msvcr100.dll (ErrorCode: 126) when webapp is deployed to Azure

Tags: sql, azure, msvcr100.dll

I tried to update sql server types nuget package which updated this package to msvcr120.dll but still I am getting the same error:

> Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 126)

Locally, its working fine. Also, I am pushing these dll.s with the build to Azure.
Below is a snapshot of the error when we try to access the deployed webapp.

[image]

Comment: Is your web app x86 or x64?

Comment: The webapp runs as an x86 app.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I had to upload the entire folder SqlServerTypes to my bin folder on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It May Because of You Missed SqlServerTypes in your Bin Folder

It Contains 2 Folders like x64 and x86 has Reference files SqlServerSpatial110.dll and msvcr100.dll

[Include those 2 DLL's in your bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNZdk.png)

Comment: Please include the file details in the answer not in an image.